# restoring multiple windows of an application at once

Tags: windows-7

Sometimes I am working on several cygwin command line windows and for some 
reason I get them all minimized pressing win+D, but then I am unable to 
bring them back up where they were without clicking each one of them.  I 
really hate this because sometimes I do this often and I screw myself up 
when I have to bring like 8 back up again.  Is there a command in windows 
7 to bring them all up at once.

If there isn't, is there a way I can program one?

Answer (score 0):

If you press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> again, it should restore all of the windows back to where they were.

Comment: It doesn't after I switch to something else, which is often what I do.